# matching first occurrence of a character

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a Base64 string that can start with `data:image/png;base64` or any other format like `data:video/mp4` based on the file uploaded by the user, i am writing an ajax call for a function that should take that base64 string and fetch it's type and something later

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RD.....
```

so if all the base64 string should start with : `data:type/type;base64,` i want to find the first occurence of `,` and then save the `data:type/type;base64` in a string to know the type and make my original base64 string look like this : `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RD....`

what i did is this :

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "Uploadfile.aspx/uploadfile",
        data: '{ "fileData" : "' + data+ '" }',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            alert('Image saved successfully !');
        }
    });
```

where `data` is the whole base64 string

c#

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static void uploadfile(string fileData)
{
  Regex r = new Regex(/[^;]*/);
  Match m = r.Match(fileData);
   while (m.Success)
   {
      // how can i continue my function 
   }

}
```

is my logic correct or there is a better way to do that ,and how can i continue my function can anyone help . i am stuck and i don't know how to continue

Comment: [StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I'm not sure if I misread your question or not, otherwise you could still just find the `IndexOf` `,` and then take a substring, no need for regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
Regex r = new Regex("^data:(.*?);base64,(.*?)$");
Match m = r.Match(fileData);
if(m.Success) {
    string mimeType = m.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Which matches the pattern:

> data:**MimeType**;base64,**FileData**

Meaning `m.Groups[1]` will contain the MIME Type and `m.Groups[2]` will contain the base64-encoded string data.